# Getting error in production while running npm run build command with absolute path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

**jsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "src",
  "paths": {
    "*": ["src/*"]
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "start:dev": "PORT=8000  env-cmd -e development react-scripts start",
  "start:prod": "PORT=8000 env-cmd -e production react-scripts start",
  "build:dev": "env-cmd -e development  react-scripts build",
  "build:prod": "env-cmd -e production  react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

When I run `npm run build:prod`, I encounter the following error:

```
Failed to compile.
./src/index.js
Cannot find module: ‘context/SidebarContext’. Make sure this package is installed.
You can install this package by running: npm install context/SidebarContext.
```

However, I don't face this error while in development. Can you please guide me on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: The NPM module `context` does not have any units called `SidebarContext`,  You maybe have some configuration options that's overriding this, but looking at what you have posted I'm not seeing it.

Comment: i am using absolute path everywhere and if i using relative path then not creating any error but in absolute path creating error while building production build on a server and context is folder where i am writing all context api

Comment: In nodejs.  unless you have some other configuration options, `‘context/` is NOT an absolute path, it's a reference to NPM module called `context` ->  this one here -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/context

Comment: not in context but everywhere i am getting this error ,[Failed to compile.
./src/layout/Layout.jsx
Cannot find module: ‘routes’. Make sure this package is installed.
You can install this package by running: npm install routes.]

Comment: `"*": ["src/*"]`  Where did you get this from?, your basically saying every modules package will get resolved to the `src` directory, but this will only be for Typescript unless you have loaders in place for your build, eg.  If you was using webpack you would require https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin to use them,.  A common approach to using paths in ts for making directories easier is ``"~": ["src/*"]`  and then you could do `~context/SidebarContext` and then normal NPM's modules can still be used.  But again your build needs to know about this.